# Maven Packaging a Few Shaded Jars

Tags: java, maven, zip

I am currently running a multi-module maven project and in each module I'm generating a shaded jar.  These jars are meant to run separately as they represent *three* different Spark jobs.

However in the desire to make "shipping" them somewhere easier, I would like to zip all these shaded jars up.  I've tried using the assembly plugin to achieve this but I'm struggling.

When I try to use module sets, it *only* seems to grab the unshaded jar.

I've been able to achieve this using filesets, but it's not very elegant and additionally it doesn't handle the fact that I have development and production builds which alter the naming of the shaded jars.

I am assuming that module sets is still the right way to go, but I'm not sure how to get it to grab my shaded jars and *only* the shaded jars.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "shaded jar"?

Comment: Please show your pom file and your assembly descriptor...

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, based on the examples [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/generate-assembly.html):

1) A parent pom with your shaded jar projects, then a distribution project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>assembly-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>assembly-example</name>

    <modules>
        <module>shaded-jar-1</module>
        <module>shaded-jar-2</module>
        <module>distribution</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

2) Shaded jar projects like this I've used as an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>assembly-example</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>shaded-jar-1</artifactId>

  <name>shaded-jar-1</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.greg.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

3) A distribution project that will build the final zip

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>assembly-example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>distribution</artifactId>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Distribution</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>distro-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

4) A bin.xml to control the building of the zip

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

    <id>bin</id>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>

            <!-- Enable access to all projects in the current multimodule build! -->
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

            <!-- Now, select which projects to include in this module-set. -->
            <includes>
                <include>com.greg:shaded-jar-1</include>
                <include>com.greg:shaded-jar-2</include>
            </includes>
            <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>modules/maven-assembly-plugin</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>

</assembly>
```

This will give you a zip with fat jars in

```
jar tvf distribution/target/distribution-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip 
     0 Fri Jun 15 10:37:32 BST 2018 modules/
     0 Fri Jun 15 10:37:32 BST 2018 modules/maven-assembly-plugin/
501520 Fri Jun 15 10:37:30 BST 2018 modules/maven-assembly-plugin/shaded-jar-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
501520 Fri Jun 15 10:37:30 BST 2018 modules/maven-assembly-plugin/shaded-jar-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Check that your shade plugin is working correctly, in your traget folder you should have a fat jar and an original jar, the fat jar is the 'defaut' artifact.

```
greg@greg-XPS-13-9360:~/work/assembly-example$ ls -l shaded-jar-1/target/
total 520
drwxrwxr-x 3 greg greg   4096 Jun 15 10:37 classes
drwxrwxr-x 3 greg greg   4096 Jun 15 10:37 generated-sources
drwxrwxr-x 3 greg greg   4096 Jun 15 10:37 generated-test-sources
drwxrwxr-x 2 greg greg   4096 Jun 15 10:37 maven-archiver
drwxrwxr-x 3 greg greg   4096 Jun 15 10:37 maven-status
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg greg   2418 Jun 15 10:37 original-shaded-jar-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg greg 501520 Jun 15 10:37 shaded-jar-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
drwxrwxr-x 3 greg greg   4096 Jun 15 10:37 test-classes
```

Comment: This is essentially what I've been trying.  I did not have that binaries section before.  But even with adding that, I **do not** get the shaded jar.  I get the regular jar and **all** of it's dependencies.

Comment: Work for me, you can get my example [here](https://github.com/gregclinker/assembly-example) and try and see what's different.

Comment: See updated answer, check your shade plugin is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In a `distribution` module on the same level as your existing modules (here `module1` and `module2`, create an `src/assembly/bin.xml` using `fileSets` instead of `moduleSets`:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>../module1/target</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>*-shaded.jar</include>
      </includes>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>../module2/target</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>*-shaded.jar</include>
      </includes>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The `pom.xml` for the distribution project is same as usual:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>group-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>distro-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</assembly>
```